# 0 not passing a if statement if != 0 ? string compared to string

Tags: php

i am just fixing some form validation, and i seem to have a very odd issue.

```
$newsletter = $_POST['newsletter']; // value 0 or 1 is passed from form, as "value"
// input type is radiobuttens
```

then i have a very simple

```
if ($newsletter != "0" || $newsletter != "1") {
    $error_message .= 'Invalid newsletter?<br />';
}
```

it does not pass this? i did try:

```
if ($newsletter != 0 || $newsletter != 1) {
```

does not pass either, but thats comparing a string to an int as far as i know

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Edit: **What do you get if you echo $newsletter ? That will probably help you answer it yourself**

Comment: Im trying to filter the validation and prevent html editing, i have a form with a input type radiobutten newsletter, yes = 1 no = 0, very simple, it gets sent to the form, and i want to filter it and return an error if it does not = 1 or 0

Comment: I think you need `&&` instead of `||` in the query - an OR is matched if either side is true, and the number is always going to be a 0 (which matches != 1) or 1 (which matches != 0)

Comment: `x != A || x != B` is always true iff `A != B`.

Comment: @JohnDOe: You mean you want to return an error if it does not = 1 *and* 0. It will always not = 1 *or* 0. If it's 1, it's not 0. If it's 0, it's not 1.

Comment: I get 0 or 1 depending on what i pick, value is OK

Comment: I am a retard it is supposed to be and

Comment: delete this question ... damn embaracing

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change the statement to `&&`

```
if ($newsletter != "0" && $newsletter != "1") {
```

This will check if it is neither 0 nor 1.

Answer (score 0):

If it's "0", it's not "1". If it's "1", it's not "0". So it will always either not be zero or not be one. No value would pass that test.

You only want to return an error if it's not equal to "1" *and* it's also not equal to "0".

Answer (score 0):

Answering the comment, you can just do:

```
if(!$newsletter) { $error_message .= 'Invalid newsletter?<br />'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an `AND` comparison.  I am assuming that you want to make sure that only a value of 0 or 1 is passed to the script.

```
if ($newsletter != "0" && $newsletter != "1") {
    $error_message .= 'Invalid newsletter?<br />';
}
```

Since 0 != 1 either of side of your `OR` condition was true.  So this always passed.